# Django QuerySet with nested ForeignKey Model

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models one is for products and one for Shop. People will register an online shop and upload their products. Now I need to get the list of products in that Shop while I am creating context in my view. Following is the code:

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, blank=False)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text="Enter a Name for your Shop")
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, help_text="Introduce your Shop in 200 words")
    shop_owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False, help_text='Enter name of the Owner of Shop.')
    shop_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to_shop, null=True)
    shop_city = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Enter name of City Where your Shop is located.")
    shop_province = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Enter then name of Province shop is located at.')
    shop_country = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="If not in Pakistan please specify your Country")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text='Enter Street Address for your Shop for Verification')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)
    hits = models.ManyToManyField(HitCount, blank=True)
    hitcounts = GenericRelation(HitCount, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk',)
```

DetailView for Shops:

```
class ShopDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Shop
    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShopDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        return context
```

Comment: So, those are the models. What is your view? Where exactly are you having trouble? What is "nested" here?

Comment: I tried different things but didn't worked. I am trying to get it into my detail view. In my list view it will have all the list of Shops and in DetailView it will have list of products related to particular shop. I am adding my DetailView code above.

Comment: That view doesn't show anything; the `get_context_data` method does nothing at all and is completely pointless. I'm still unsure of where you are having difficulties; *exactly* what did you try, and what went wrong?

Comment: All the example I've tried from Stackoverflow but I didn't posted it because I was afraid that it might look like below standard. I am new to djagno so will be glad if you could help. All I need is to design a context that presents products saved to a shop with pk reference.

Comment: Yes. So, you have the Shop already, and the shop has a `products` attribute which lists all its products, so *what is the problem*?

Comment: I did it like shop_related=Products.objects.filter(shop__shop_name__exact=_myshopname_). But I couldn't understand how to filter related to shop name.

Comment: Why do you think you need to filter anything? As I just said, you *have* the shop, and the shop *has* a list of all its products. There is literally nothing else to be done. (In any case, that code would also work, so I also don't understand what you are unclear about there either.)

Comment: When I use {{ shop.products }} in template it gives me "Shop.products.Product" and that's it

Comment: Kindly tell me one thing...if in Shop model I present {{ shop.products }} in template what result should I expect? All the related to products to shop. Right?

Comment: `shop.products` is a queryset of all products related to the shop. You need to use `shop.products.all`, and iterate over it.

Comment: Wow great...that's what I was looking for from last two hours. It worked. Post as answer.